# Unexpected results from Area.intersect()

Tags: java, awt, graphics2d

I am attempting to get the intersection of two polygons via `Area.intersect()`, but in some cases I am getting a strange result.

My code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel = new Panel();
        frame.add(panel);
    }

    static class Panel extends JPanel
    {
        Panel()
        {
            setBackground(new Color(0, 50, 0));
            setFocusable(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g1)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g1);
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1;
            
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.scale(3,3);
            g.transform(at);
            
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            
            Path2D.Double path1 = new Path2D.Double();
            
            path1.append(new Line2D.Double(76,  62,                 31, 62                  ),true);
            path1.append(new Line2D.Double(31,  62,                 31, 70.00000000000001   ),true);
            path1.append(new Line2D.Double(31,  70.00000000000001,  76, 70                  ),true);
            
            Area area1 = new Area(path1);

            Path2D.Double path2 = new Path2D.Double();
            
            path2.append(new Line2D.Double(52, 10,52,130),true);
            path2.append(new Line2D.Double(52, 130,60,130),true);
            path2.append(new Line2D.Double(60, 130,60.0,10),true);

            Area area2 = new Area(path2);
            
            g.fill(area1);
            
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fill(area2);
            
            Area areaIntersect = new Area(path1);
            areaIntersect.intersect(area2);
            
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.draw(areaIntersect);
            
            PathIterator pi = areaIntersect.getPathIterator(null);

            while(!pi.isDone())
            {
                double[] coords = new double[6];
                switch(pi.currentSegment(coords))
                {
                    case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
                        break;
                    case PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO:
                        System.out.println(coords[4] + "," + coords[5]);
                    case PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO:
                        System.out.println(coords[2] + "," + coords[3]);
                    case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                    case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                        System.out.println(coords[0] + "," + coords[1]);
                }
                pi.next();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the result:

[image]

The intersection should just be a yellow square; the long yellow horizontal line should not be part of the result.

I know that the problem relates to the very tiny angle of the bottom of the blue box:
`Line2D.Double(31,70.00000000000001,76,70)`.  If I change 70.00000000000001 to nearly any other value, the intersection box displays correctly.  For example, changing both of them to 70.000000000001:

```
            path1.append(new Line2D.Double(31,  62,                 31, 70.000000000001 ),true);
            path1.append(new Line2D.Double(31,  70.000000000001,    76, 70                  ),true);
```

[image]

I printed the coordinates of the generated intersect, to make sure what I was seeing was not a display problem, but it clearly shows the line from 31.0 to 76.0 on the x axis, whereas it should only be 52.0 to 60.0.

```
52.0,60.0
52.0,70.00000000000001
31.0,70.00000000000001
76.0,70.0
60.0,70.0
60.0,60.0
```

I am doing some trigonometry to generate the polygons, so values like .00000000000001 are expected.  I *could* round them off, but without knowing what's causing the problem, I'm worried that it might occur with other values.

**Update** using MadProgrammer's answer but changing path1 to:

```
    Path2D.Double path1 = new Path2D.Double();
    path1.append(new Line2D.Double(31, 62,                  76, 62), true);
    path1.append(new Line2D.Double(76, 62,                  76, 70.0000000000001), true);
    path1.append(new Line2D.Double(76, 70.0000000000001,    31, 70), true);
    path1.append(new Line2D.Double(31, 70, 31, 62), true);
    path1.closePath();
```

..produces a slightly less-wrong result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, I removed the scaling, that didn't help.

Next I added `closePath` to both the paths, that didn't help.

Next, I add an additional line to each path to ensure that the paths were closed correctly, that didn't help.

Next I used `Rectangle2D` instead of `Path` and solved the issue.  So the problem lies with the `Path`s.

Next, I changed the intersection to use the pre-existing `Area`s instead of the first `Path` and the second `Area`.

```
Area areaIntersect = new Area(area1);
areaIntersect.intersect(area2);
```

this didn't help.

Now I'm scratching my head.  I went back and compared the `Path` with the `Rectangle2D` and noted that path one "seems" to have a counter clock wise winding, so I changed it to have a clock wise winding instead...

```
Path2D.Double path1 = new Path2D.Double();
path1.append(new Line2D.Double(31, 62, 76, 62), true);
path1.append(new Line2D.Double(76, 62, 76, 70.00000000000001), true);
path1.append(new Line2D.Double(76, 70.00000000000001, 31, 70.00000000000001), true);
path1.append(new Line2D.Double(31, 70.00000000000001, 31, 62), true);
path1.closePath();
```

and that worked!

There also could be an issue with the difference between `70` and `70.00000000000001` although in my updated test, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Why would the winding matter?  In this case, I can't say, but it just seems to make a difference.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

                JPanel panel = new TestPane();
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class TestPane extends JPanel {

        TestPane() {
            setBackground(new Color(0, 50, 0));
            setFocusable(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g1) {
            super.paintComponent(g1);
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1;

            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.scale(3, 3);
            g.transform(at);

            Path2D.Double path1 = new Path2D.Double();
            path1.append(new Line2D.Double(31, 62, 76, 62), true);
            path1.append(new Line2D.Double(76, 62, 76, 70.00000000000001), true);
            path1.append(new Line2D.Double(76, 70.00000000000001, 31, 70.00000000000001), true);
            path1.append(new Line2D.Double(31, 70, 31, 62), true);
            path1.closePath();

            Path2D.Double path2 = new Path2D.Double();

            path2.append(new Line2D.Double(52, 10, 52, 130), true);
            path2.append(new Line2D.Double(52, 130, 60, 130), true);
            path2.append(new Line2D.Double(60, 130, 60.0, 10), true);
            path2.append(new Line2D.Double(60.0, 10, 52, 10), true);
            path2.closePath();

            Area area1 = new Area(path1);
            Area area2 = new Area(path2);

            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.draw(area1);

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.draw(area2);

            Area areaIntersect = new Area(area1);
            areaIntersect.intersect(area2);

            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.draw(areaIntersect);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, MadProgrammer, but I don't think it's the winding.  I was able to reproduce the problem (although not exactly) with your code but using a value of 70.0000000000001.  Note that the problem doesn't happen with an exactly horizontal line (i.e., from 70.0000000000001 to 70.0000000000001), so I'm sure the tiny angle has something to do with it.  I updated my answer with the change I made to your code, and an image of the result.  Interestingly, I can also "fix" my original code by changing the two x values of 76 to 80...

Comment: @Joe In my experimentation, I was able to use both `70.00000000000001` and `70` together without issues

Comment: it wasn't just mixing the two, it was a different number: 70.0000000000001 vs. 70.00000000000001.

Comment: @Joe You may be right, but since I didn't have much of issues between `70....` and `70` it didn't figure into my investigations, since the shapes were closed 